# java awt Canvas getInstance undefined (newbie)

Tags: java, canvas

Trying the exercise in lesson2 of the Udacity course. Despite importing the classes (I'm at java.awt.* now, but I also tried java.awt.Color and java.awt.Canvas separately (also need Shape))..

```js
package com.jul.udacity.lesson2;

public class TestRectangle {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 100.0);
  rect1.draw();
  }
}
```

And the class is copied from there and java.awt import added. Any help will be great. Thanks!

```js
package com.jul.udacity.lesson2;

//HIDE
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
//import java.awt.Color;
//import java.awt.Shape;
//import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.*;


public class Rectangle implements Shape
{
  private Color color = Color.BLACK;
  private boolean filled = false;
  private double x;
  private double y;
  private double width;
  private double height;

  /**
     Constructs an empty rectangle.
  */
  public Rectangle()
  {
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
      width = 0;
      height = 0;
  }       

  /**
     Constructs a rectangle.
     @param x the leftmost x-coordinate
     @param y the topmost y-coordinate
     @param width the width
     @param height the height
  */
  public Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height)
  {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
  }

  /**
     Gets the leftmost x-position of this rectangle.
     @return the leftmost x-position
  */
  public int getX()
  {
      return (int) Math.round(x);
  }

  /**
     Gets the topmost y-position of this rectangle.
     @return the topmost y-position
  */
  public int getY()
  {
      return (int) Math.round(y);
  }

  /**
     Gets the width of this rectangle.
     @return the width
  */    
  public int getWidth()
  {
      return (int) Math.round(width);
  }

  /**
     Gets the height of this rectangle.
     @return the height
  */    
  public int getHeight()
  {
      return (int) Math.round(height);
  }

  /**
     Moves this rectangle by a given amount.
     @param dx the amount by which to move in x-direction
     @param dy the amount by which to move in y-direction
  */
  public void translate(double dx, double dy)
  {
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
      Canvas.getInstance().repaint();
  }

  /**
     Resizes this rectangle both horizontally and vertically.
     @param dw the amount by which to resize the width on each side
     @param dw the amount by which to resize the height on each side
  */
  public void grow(double dw, double dh)
  {
      width += 2 * dw;
      height += 2 * dh;
      x -= dw;
      y -= dh;
      Canvas.getInstance().repaint();
  }

  /**
     Sets the color of this rectangle.
     @param newColor the new color
  */
  public void setColor(Color newColor)
  {
      color = newColor;
      Canvas.getInstance().repaint();
  }

  /**
     Draws this rectangle.
  */
  public void draw()
  {
      filled = false;
      Canvas.getInstance().show(this);
  }

  /**
     Fills this rectangle.
  */
  public void fill()
  {
      filled = true;
      Canvas.getInstance().show(this);
  }

  public String toString()
  {
      return "Rectangle[x=" + getX() + ",y=" + getY() + ",width=" + getWidth() + ",height=" + getHeight() + "]";
  }

  public void paintShape(Graphics2D g2)
  {
      Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(getX(), getY(),
              getWidth(), getHeight());
      g2.setColor(new java.awt.Color((int) color.getRed(), (int) color.getGreen(), (int) color.getBlue()));
      if (filled)
      {
          g2.fill(rect);
      }
      else
      {
          g2.draw(rect);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the lesson directions carefully.  `java.awt.Canvas` has no `getInstance()` method.  You just use `new` to make a `Canvas`.  So you either didn't read carefully and are using the wrong Canvas, or there's something else going on.

Also the `show()` methods are deprecated, so I'm leaning towards you are supposed to be using a different Canvas class.

Also, [Swing is not thread safe.  Read up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) on how to use Swing objects

Answer (score 0):

[markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338547/markspace) is correct: Canvas here is not the class from java.awt - the [Udacity instructors](https://in.udacity.com/course/intro-to-java-programming--cs046/) are using their own class called Canvas. I suggest grabbing the lesson files and using those. Here's the Canvas class from that Intro To Java Course:

```
  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;
  import java.awt.image.RescaleOp;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import javax.swing.JComponent;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Canvas
  {
    private static Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    private BufferedImage background;
    private JFrame frame;
    private CanvasComponent component;

    private static final int MIN_SIZE = 100;
    private static final int MARGIN = 10;
    private static final int LOCATION_OFFSET = 120;

  class CanvasComponent extends JComponent
  {
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
      {
          g.setColor(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
          g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
          g.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
          if (background != null)
          {
              g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
          }               
          for (Shape s : new ArrayList<Shape>(shapes))
          {
              Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
              s.paintShape(g2);
              g2.dispose();
          }
      }

      public Dimension getPreferredSize()
      {
          int maxx = MIN_SIZE;
          int maxy = MIN_SIZE;
          if (background != null)
          {
              maxx = Math.max(maxx, background.getWidth());
              maxy = Math.max(maxx, background.getHeight());
          }
          for (Shape s : shapes)
          {
              maxx = (int) Math.max(maxx, s.getX() + s.getWidth());
              maxy = (int) Math.max(maxy, s.getY() + s.getHeight());
          }
          return new Dimension(maxx + MARGIN, maxy + MARGIN);
      }
  }

  private Canvas()
  {
      component = new CanvasComponent();

      if (System.getProperty("com.horstmann.codecheck") == null)
      {
          frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.add(component);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocation(LOCATION_OFFSET, LOCATION_OFFSET);
          frame.setVisible(true);
      }
      else
      {
          final String SAVEFILE ="canvas.png";
          final Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
          Thread watcherThread = new Thread() 
              {
                  public void run()
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          final int DELAY = 10;

                          while (currentThread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED)
                          {
                              Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                          }
                          saveToDisk(SAVEFILE);
                      }
                      catch (Exception ex)
                      {
                          ex.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
              };
          watcherThread.start();
      }
  }

  public static Canvas getInstance()
  {
      return canvas;
  }

  public void show(Shape s)
  {
      if (!shapes.contains(s))
      {
          shapes.add(s);
      }
      repaint();
  }

  public void repaint()
  {
      if (frame == null) return;
      Dimension dim = component.getPreferredSize();
      if (dim.getWidth() > component.getWidth()
              || dim.getHeight() > component.getHeight())
      {
          frame.pack();
      }
      else
      {
          frame.repaint();
      }
  }

    /**
     * Pauses so that the user can see the picture before it is transformed.
     */
    public void pause()
    {
        if (frame == null) return;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Click Ok to continue");
    }

    /**
     * Takes a snapshot of the screen, fades it, and sets it as the background.
     */
    public static void snapshot()
    {
        Dimension dim = getInstance().component.getPreferredSize();
        java.awt.Rectangle rect = new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(rect.width, rect.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
        getInstance().component.paintComponent(g);
        float factor = 0.8f;
        float base = 255f * (1f - factor);
        RescaleOp op = new RescaleOp(factor, base, null);
        BufferedImage filteredImage
           = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getType());
        op.filter(image, filteredImage);
        getInstance().background = filteredImage;
        getInstance().component.repaint();
    }

    public void saveToDisk(String fileName)
    {
        Dimension dim = component.getPreferredSize();
        java.awt.Rectangle rect = new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(rect.width, rect.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        g.fill(rect);
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
        component.paintComponent(g);
        String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        try
        {
            ImageIO.write(image, extension, new File(fileName));
        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Was unable to save the image to " + fileName);
        }
        g.dispose();        
    }
}
```